# ng-repeat can't repeat google maps to all list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have some problem when use ng-repeat tho show 3 list. Firsr list is ok because google map show but in second list and third list. this my html

```
<ion-list>
            <ion-item class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="i in rep">
                <div class="card card-wraper" >
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap" >
                        <div id="map"></div>
                        <div id="over_map">
                            <label >
                                <span class="input-label"></span>
                                <input input placeholder="Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type = 'date')" ng-model="trip">
                            </label>
                            <div >            
                                <select  ng-options="size as size.code for size in sizes" ng-model="item" style="background-color:#262261;color: white"ng-change="update(item)"></select>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

and this my controller

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {  


      $scope.trip = new Date();
      $scope.item = {};
            $scope.code = {};
            $scope.sizes = [{code: 123456789, name: 'Modul 1'}, {code: 864369038803163, name: 'Modul 2'},
                {code: 864369038796946, name: 'Modul 4'}, {code: 864369038803833, name: 'Modul 5'},
                {code: 864369038816645, name: 'Modul 6'}, {code: 864369038797142, name: 'Modul 7'},
                {code: 864369038796698, name: 'Modul 8'}];
            $scope.update = function (selected) {
                $scope.item = selected;
            };

   $scope.rep.push(i);
  }
```

I don't know how to fix it please help me solve this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that id in DOM elements is unique, your repeater create 3 DOM elements with id `map`. The DOM selector 
`document.getElementById("map")` pick only one of them. you should create different id's or use class selector in order to create more than one map.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in ng-repeat, it happening due to multple elements with same id i.e "`<div id="map"></div>`"

**Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.**
in case of multple elements with same id HTML DOM considers only first element of that id and ignores others next to it hence only first list with id map is generating map.

Try to select with **class** instead of **id**.

Select map with **Multiple ids**

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map0 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsById("map0"), myOptions);
    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsById("map1"), myOptions);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsById("map2"), myOptions);

}
```

and add a **$index(starts with 0)** in html

```
<div id="map{{$index}}"></div>
```

Comment: map not show and have error like this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: What if i dont know how many elements are there in ng-repeat?then how can i assign different ids for map?